# Doing multiple tasks at once? (combining a GUI related function to carryout some process)

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, console-application, winsock

I'm sorry if the title sounds "off", but to elaborate further, this is my problem - Basically I've written a simple Winsock `server` which passes information (text messages) between connected clients (This is the console application). Now for this program I've tried combining what I've learned from the [win32api](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) with the *`client` program*. Now getting a little ahead of my self I went ahead and wrote the basic look for the UI but now I don't know how to combine the two?. From what I understand ( :| ) the console application is running from top-bottom sequentially while a UI is continuously drawing the window on the screen and waiting for something to happen. So to finally get to the point, how do I combine these too??. I'm quite put off by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GUI works through an event-driven message-loop. That message-loop dispatches incoming events to function-calls. So if you press a button, a function is called, which then can call for instance the network `send`-function. If you need to send (or receive) large amounts of data, you should create a separate thread and message-loop just for the network stuff, so that the GUI stays responsive.

Comment: Where can I find more information on threads?. What would you recommend for a beginner?.

Comment: If you are transmitting only small amounts of data and your network latency is not too high, you can also do it without threads.

Comment: You can use overlapped I/O with the Win32 API. Depending on your mindset, that may be easier or harder than threads. With overlapped I/O, Windows will call you when data is available. Another solution is `WSAAsyncSelect`, which tells Windows to send a message to your HWND.